# How to refer file in GSC buckets(not the cloud composer one) from Cloud composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

We have a requirement in which we use a shell script to validate some files. The script needs to validate some files in another bucket(not the cloud composer one) as part of it's functionality. Understand we can place the script validate.sh in DAG folder as mentioned below

```
import os

DAGS_FOLDER = os.environ["DAGS_FOLDER"]
file = f"{DAGS_FOLDER}/validate.sh"
```

But this file will accept parameter in a gcs bucket like this f"{DAGS_FOLDER}/validate.sh gs://another-bucket/feed.txt"

Any idea how to achieve this please.

Regards;
Gopal